# how can I select the values Kendo MultiselectTextBox in a protractor test

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, automation, protractor

How can i select the values in kendo multi select and enter the values using protractor.
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/api

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example working test suite demonstrating how to select an element from the Kendo Dropdown - "Pulp Fiction" in this case. You can then extend the example to work in your use case:

```
"use strict";

describe("Kendo Multi-Select", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/api");
    });

    it("should select a movie", function () {
        // click the input to trigger the dropdown
        var movieInput = $("input[aria-owns*=movies_taglist]");
        movieInput.click();

        // filter an item from the dropdown
        var movieToSelect = $$("div#movies-list li.k-item").filter(function (movie) {
            return movie.getText().then(function (movieText) {
                return movieText === "Pulp Fiction";
            })
        }).first();

        // move to the element and click
        browser.actions().mouseMove(movieToSelect).click().perform();

        // expectations
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of the filter() you can use element(by.cssContainingText('li', 'Pulp Fiction')).click();

Comment: @Gerfried yup, and and xpath as well. "by css containing text" though would also match things like `Hello, Pulp Fiction, world` and it depends on a use case if the "contains" match is good enough and would not produce false positives. Good point anyway.

Comment: Good point - I was not aware that cssContainingText has a "contains" instead of an "equals" condition. Thanks.